# Solving a Tridiagonal Matrix using Eigen package in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

At present I have a system **Ax** = **b** such that **A** is a tridiagonal matrix. Using Eigen, I can already solve this system using the line:

x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);

However, since **A** is a tridiagonal matrix this works rather slowly compared to say in MATLAB, since the program is mostly likely computing the solution for all values rather than just on the three diagonals. Can Eigen solve this system faster? This is probably quite a dumb questions but I'm fairly new to C++ and I only started using Eigen a few days ago so there's a lot to take in at the moment! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to implement the Thomas algorithm yourself. Nothing can beat the speed of that. The algorithm is so simple, that nor Eigen nor BLAS will beat your hand-written code. In case you have to solve a series of matrices, the procedure is very well vectorizable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

If you want to stick with standard libraries, the BLAS DGTSV (double precision) or SGTSV (single precision) is probably the best solution.

Comment: Of course it's true if I implement the algorithm myself it would be much quicker :) I know this might sound kinda bad, but right now though I'm only interested in something that's quick to implement into the code which can also compute the solutions of the system faster than what I currently have, only because I have several other codes which I have to write up in very little time...

Comment: In that case, go for the BLAS ?GTSV routine.

Comment: On second thought the Thomas algorithm does look quite easy to implement, I didn't read through it properly at first but it actually looks extremely easy and quick to write up. Thanks for telling me about it!

Comment: @ThePlowKing it is really only a few lines of codes and the algorithm is super fast. You can find a vectorized version that I have written myself in the following file (function name tdma): https://github.com/microhh/microhh/blob/master/src/pres_2.cxx

Comment: Thanks heaps for that! :)

Comment: @Chiel, Are you aware of other Multi Threaded and Vectorized implementation of Tridiagonal Matrix System solvers? I saw Intel MKL's [?gtsv](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-gtsv) and [?gbsv](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-gbsv). I wonder if there is even better (Less overhead) implementation.

Comment: @Royi, it depends on whether you want to optimize the speed of a single very large matrix solver, or whether you want to solve many of the same systems simultaneously.

Comment: @Chiel, I have cases for both so I would be happy for reference for each.